# MySQL5.7 service not starting on windows server after changing datadir path. But starts with default datadir path?

Tags: mysql

I have installed MySQL community Edition 5.7 on Windows Server 2012 R2.

The mysql my.ini file is located under ProgramData/Mysql/MySQL community server 5.7/

Before changing the data dir path I stop mysql57 service as net stop mysql57.

Then I change the datadir path to located on a different drive on the same machine.

Then I start the services again with net start mysql57 . But the services fails to start and throws 1067 system error.

But if I reverted the datadir path to old one i.e the default one the services start successfully.

I am unable to solve this issue. Please help regarding this.

Comment: Permissions set up properly? In any case not a programming issue, so should be elsewhere

Comment: please show datadir line from .ini